# node.js - Will buffer with 'space.repeat' works same way across browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, buffer, spaces

I am trying to return the below string from Node.js response object to React app with some predefined spaces added manually in between buffer variables this way,

```
const space = ' ';
const nextLine = '\r\n';

const nodeResp = Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from(` This ${nextLine}`),
    Buffer.from(` is ${nextLine} `),
    Buffer.from(` a ${nextLine}`),
    Buffer.from(`Sample ${space.repeat(84)} : yess ${nextLine}`),
    Buffer.from(`React ${space.repeat(85)} : nooo ${nextLine}`),
    Buffer.from(`App ${space.repeat(87)} : yess ${nextLine}`),
    Buffer.from('From Node.')]);

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain').send(nodeResp);
```

Will the 'space.repeat' methods returns the same space, across the browsers and across the resolutions?

I mean the output displayed from my above code will be same way on all resolutions/browsers or it my result in different spaces in different environments/operating systems.

I am learning node js and need some help in this regard.

Can someone guide me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The repeat method of string prototype that you used here, as long as the variable that you are repeating does not change you're going to get the same result.